# How can imparted energy be a stochastic quantity?

Tags: energy, radiation, radioactivity, stochastic-processes

It may be a silly question, but I have a dosimetry course and it started by defining deposed energy and imparted energy and for both it says that they're stochastic quantities. The mathematical definitions are:
$$\epsilon_i = \epsilon_{in} - \epsilon_{out} + Q$$
Where $\epsilon_i$ is the deposed energy, $\epsilon_{in}$ is the energy of the incident particle, $\epsilon_{out}$ is the energies of the particles after the interaction and $Q$ is the variation of the energy of mass. And for the imparted energy, it's simply the sum of the deposed energies for every interaction in the volume $V$.
$$\epsilon = \sum_i \epsilon_i$$

Now I understand how the deposed energy could be stochastic because we cannot predict which interaction will take place but given that we have the information about the volume, we should be able to model the imparted energy. So how could imparted energy be stochastic ?

After all, this is the objective of dosimetry. Is there something I'm missing or is there a problem of how I'm seeing things.

P.S. : it's a bit weird that there isn't a dosimetry tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Averaged over small volumes or a small number of interactions, the quantity is stochastic. Averaged over a sufficiently large volume or number of interactions, it becomes a well-behaved average quantity. This is just the law of large numbers ... Or am I missing the point of your question?

Comment: Yeah I think this is the idea, however given the number of interactions is usually very large, it could never be just random. Thanks for your answer.